# Titanium - Rounded tableview not looks like the code

Tags: javascript, ios, tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

How can I show the rounded border in my TableView?

```
var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
data:data,
style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
borderRadius: 3
});
```

When I run the simulator, the tableview gets full screen horizontal size(from right to left) without the border.

Anyone? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to also set `borderWidth` and `borderColor`.

BTW, use `Titanium.UI.iOS.TableViewStyle.GROUPED` instead. `Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED` will be deprecated.